# Help: Ubuntu installation not working... Kernel Panic

Tags: installation, kernel, wubi

I just tried to download and install Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion desktop, I installed it on a separate 72gb partition on my hard drive with the hopes of running it alongside windows xp professional. I used the Ubuntu Windows Installer and now whenever I reboot the machine and choose Ubuntu I get a message saying Kernel Panic, I'm sorry I didn't write down the specifics but I will try to restart, write everything down, and reply with all the pertinent info. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

- M                                                                                      Hello Barry, thank you for your quick response. Let me try to clarify. My computer has a 250GB Hard Drive with 2 partitions, one of the partitions, the D: drive has 72GB of free space on it.I used the following installer, not the live-dvd, to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows The installer had a drop down menu that allowed me to select the 72 GB partition. Once the installer went through its motions, it indicated that the system would need to be rebooted in order for the installation to be complete. I rebooted it, chose Ubuntu instead of Windows XP and got the following Kernel Panic message... [ 6.005387] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount... then there are about a dozen more lines of text after that, I would try to post a picture of the screen but I don't know how to...

Sorry for the late reply John, I just saw your comments. To answer your question, yes I tried installing Ubuntu on a hard drive that I also have Windows on, the main partition, the C: drive is the one that Windows is actually installed on, and the secondary partition, the D: drive (the 72gb partition) is the one I tried installing Ubuntu on. The D; drive actually had a few random files like music and pictures on it when I tried installing Ubuntu to it. I am now reformatting that drive so that it is completely empty, once it's been formatted I will try to reinstall Ubuntu. I am not sure what Wubi is... is that something I need to run as well? I apologize for being such a noob to all of this. I'm so excited to finally try Ubuntu:)

UPDATE @ John: I tried to upload a screenshot of the KERNEL PANIC message but this message system isn't allowing me to post an image because I haven't earned at least 10 reputation points yet. I'm sorry, I just figured out that yes I did indeed use WUBI in another partition that Windows is not in. Is that my problem? Do I need to reinstall UBUNTU via WUBI in the main partion of my hard drive where Windows actually lives?

@JOHN, do you by chance know if I can just create a bootable usb flash drive to install a fresh copy of ubuntu on to my empty 72GB partition? I want to be able to dual boot.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information. Ask again with the version of Ubuntu you tried to install. What happened when you ran the live-DVD and clicked 'Try Ubuntu' and whether this was a clean install or an upgrade. One thing I am not clear about: There is a huge conflict between 'I installed it on a separate 72gb partition' and 'I used the Ubuntu Windows Installer'. Both options won't add up. Either the one or the other must be true. Please boot from the live-DVD and do the 'Try' option.

Comment: @barrydrake is (I think) asking whether you installed Ubuntu onto a separate partition on the hard drive you also have Windows installed on, or whether you used [**Wubi**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)? (I suppose a third possibility is that you used `Wubi` but in such a way that the Ubuntu VHD was placed in a different NTFS partition than the one Windows is in. But I'm probably just over-thinking this ...)

Comment: I forgot to ask you to please respond to the requests for more information by updating/editing your question. Do **not** post this information to a comment. This is how the **[faq#howtoask]** for this site recommends exchanging information.

Comment: This may help explain **[how to upload an image to a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/147712)**. Also here is more information on **[the formating to use to include an image](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#images)**.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with Wubi to know whether the split install is a problem. I wouldn't expect it to be though. If you have the space and time and want to install in the same partition Windows is in maybe you would learn something. Up to you. I would just be sure that when things go pear shaped you are uninstalling Wubi/Ubuntu completely. (Don't want to leave anything behind which might make problem isolation harder).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: If this kernel panic can still be produced it should be [reported  as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.) This will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).

Answer (score 1):

#### @Man

If you don't mind reformatting the 72 GB partition which is currently `D:` in your Windows XP configuration, then you can install 12.04 Ubuntu using either a Live CD or a Live USB.

Of course, using a Live USB is only possible if your HP Pavilion desktop allows you to boot from a USB flash drive.

Can you provide any further information about your machine? A model number? What type of CPU (processor) it uses? How much memory is installed?

---

No, Ubuntu will not install into an NTFS partition. It will have to be reformatted to one of the Linux file systems. Usually the [journaling `ext4` filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) is used.

Two possible approaches come to mind.

1. During the Ubuntu installation you will be presented with a window asking you to choose what type of an install you wish to perform. At that point you can choose the action "*Do Something Else*" and manually format and select the partitions you want to use for your Ubuntu install.

   This may be more involved than you want to get since you are new to all this.
2. If you use the Windows `Disk Management` tool and `Delete Volume` (i.e. the partition) and leave the space unused, then during install Ubuntu will suggest installing there and take care of the formating and everything else.

   The install should offer to install Ubuntu "**alongside**" Windows. This is what I  suggest you do. The image below is an example of what the "*Installation Type*" window looks like. (Though in your case I expect it will be Win XP, not Win 7).

   [image: example of 12.04 install choice]

---

#### Will a Normal Ubuntu Disk Install Be Faster Than Wubi?

Performance questions can be tricky. There are two answers.

1. Yes, of course. There is less "overhead" when Ubuntu is directly installed so one would expect it to be faster.
2. But you may not notice. It may not be fast *enough* for you to be able to tell the difference in perfromance.
   *Disclaimer:* I do not know any details about how Wubi works. I've got a partly-baked picture in my mind, but my assumptions could be completely wrong.

I am also a little bit biased in that I've never really embraced the concept of Wubi. I can see how it could make sense as an attempt to simplify installing Ubuntu for folks who are using Windows.

But if you had a more modern computer I'd be recommending using either a `VMware Player` or `VirtualBox` virtual machine instead. If your hardware supports virtualization I think that is a much friendlier route to exploring Linux when starting from a Windows (or Mac) background.

But if the only choice you have is to do a dual boot between Windows & Linux/Ubuntu, then installing directly to the drive seems to make the most sense to me.

If you have the time for it, you should install Ubuntu directly and just see what you think of the performance. You don't want to experiment later when you might have to worry about losing data.

Comment: I already reformatted the D: drive so now it is completely empty and freshly formatted, I am also waiting patiently for my Ubuntu .iso file to finish downloading so that I can create a live USB. I'll let you know how it goes. Thank you so much for all your help. I'm fairly confident that my HP will allow me to boot from a flash drive... the only thing I am concerned about now is that Windows only gave me the option to reformat the D: drive into an NTFS partition, will Ubuntu work on that?

Comment: Latest Update: I was growing impatient waiting for the UBUNTU iso file to download so I tried WUBI again and boom! Low and behold it worked this time! I reckoned it worked because I had reformatted the D: drive. That being said, I have been using it for a while now and the Ubuntu operating system does not seem snappy at all, it's running a smidge slow. Could that be because of the fact that I used WUBI instead of doing a full fledged install of UBUNTU?

Comment: MY HP has an 3 Ghz Intel Pentium 4 Processor, with 2GB of Ram. The instructions you've laid out seem pretty straightforward so I think I am going to attempt it. Do you think doing a 'normal' install of UBUNTO from a usb flash drive will make it run snappier than it does now through WUBI?